# Erro de Servidor Interno ao Importar Projeto ASP.NET no Visual Studio Code 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Olá, Sou iniciante em ASP.Net MVC e venho tentando abrir um projeto no Visual Studio 2019 que me enviaram zipado via dropbox.

Quando Compilo o Projeto não aparece nenhum erro de Construção, mas o problema é quando eu debugo usando o Google Chrome aparece esse erro de servidor interno mostrado na imagem abaixo. Tentei Reinstalar todos os pacotes mas não adiantou. Eu suponho que seja um problema do diretório, pois o diretório do arquivo de configuração que é mostrado nessa imagem era o caminho da pessoa que me passou o projeto, sendo diferente do diretório que o projeto está no meu computador.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como eu poderia configurar isto?

Tentei procurar no Stack Overflow em Português e Inglês inteiro mas não achei nada, então desde já eu agradeço!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O erro é bastante explícito. Procura o webconfig e configurações para ele

Comment: @ClaudioLopes Dentro do web.config não existe nenhuma configuração que se diz a respeito de diretório do projeto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após eu ter testado diversas coisas, descobri que o erro estava na Url do Projeto.

Ao Importar um projeto da internet, certifique-se de entrar no menu Projeto>>Propriedades de {nome do projeto}

Dentro da aba Web, certifique-se que a Porta escolhida é válida e que você criou um Diretório Virtual para o Projeto

Espero que isto ajude alguém

[image: Solução]